# Want to create a autorun flashdrive

Tags: autorun, usb-flash-drive

I want to create a flash drive that opens a exe file when it is plugged into a laptop/pc.
I dont want to make a Autorun.inf file. Those do not execute the program when it is plugged in, but give you the option of opening it. And i want it non-detectable from avast.

For my company, I need to install a new program on some of the Computers, I want to just plug in a flash drive to each of the computers and it installs my new program.

Operating systems to be used on: 7 and xp
Minimum space on each drive: 2gig
Antivirus: Avast

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is another way of automatically an .exe file without autorun, but autorun files does not run automatically in Windows Vista or higher.